# Call a stored procedure with two parameters in array

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, datatable, parameters

I want to populate combobox with data from stored procedure `pp_sp_MachineAndOp` with two parameters:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[pp_sp_MachineAndOp]
    @MachineAndOpID int,
    @Seq int
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF @MachineAndOpID = 0
        --Show All
        IF @Seq = 0
            SELECT 
                mo.*,
                o.Operation, o.Seq,
                m.Machine
            FROM 
                [dbo].[pp_MachineAndOp] mo
            INNER JOIN  
                pp_Machines m ON m.MachineID = mo.MachineID
            INNER JOIN 
                pp_vw_Operations o ON o.OperationID = mo.OperationID
            WHERE 
                m.Active = 1
            ORDER BY 
                mo.OperationID, MachinePriority

        ELSE
            --show all following operations
            SELECT 
                mo.*,
                o.Operation, o.Seq,
                m.Machine
            FROM 
                [dbo].[pp_MachineAndOp] mo
            INNER JOIN 
                pp_Machines m ON m.MachineID = mo.MachineID
            INNER JOIN 
                pp_vw_Operations o ON o.OperationID = mo.OperationID
            WHERE
                m.Active = 1 AND o.Seq > @Seq
            ORDER BY 
                mo.OperationID, MachinePriority

    ELSE
        -- Show Selected
        SELECT 
            mo.*,
            o.Operation, o.Seq,
            m.Machine
        FROM 
            [dbo].[pp_MachineAndOp] mo
        INNER JOIN 
            pp_Machines m ON m.MachineID = mo.MachineID
        INNER JOIN 
            pp_vw_Operations o ON o.OperationID = mo.OperationID 
        WHERE
            m.Active = 1 
            AND mo.MachineAndOpID = @MachineAndOpID
        ORDER BY 
            mo.OperationID, MachinePriority
END
```

If I execute this in SQL Server Management Studio, it works just fine.

In C# I have this method to get data from the stored procedure:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteDataTable(string storedProcedureName, params SqlParameter[] arrParam)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    // Open the connection 
    using (SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(strConn))
    {
        try
        {
            sqlConn.Open();

            // Define the command 
            using (SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                sqlCmd.Connection = sqlConn;
                sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                sqlCmd.CommandText = storedProcedureName;

                // Handle the parameters 
                if (arrParam != null)
                {
                    foreach (SqlParameter param in arrParam)
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.Add(param);
                    }
                }

                // Define the data adapter and fill the dataset 
                using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCmd))
                {
                    da.Fill(dt);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, Application.ProductName, MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
    }

    return dt;
}
```

If I call it like this I get no error and results as expected:

```
DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", 
                                         new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", "0"), 
                                         new SqlParameter("@Seq", "0"));
```

If I call it like this

```
DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", 
                                         new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", "0"), 
                                         new SqlParameter("@Seq", "7"));
```

I get an error

> Parameter @MachineAndOpID not supplied

The same error I get on this call:

```
DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", 
                                         new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID",0), 
                                         new SqlParameter("@Seq", 0));
```

and here:

```
DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp", 
                                         new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID",SqlDbType.BigInt, 0), 
                                         new SqlParameter("@Seq",SqlDbType.BigInt, 7));
```

I feel like it somehow related with datatype but cannot figure out how to solve it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must define the correct data type.
It should work like this:

```
DataTable dtMO = Helper.ExecuteDataTable("pp_sp_MachineAndOp",
                                           new SqlParameter("@MachineAndOpID", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 6 },
                                           new SqlParameter("@Seq", SqlDbType.Int) { Value = 6 });
```

See here: [Data Type Mappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql-server-data-type-mappings)

Comment: Thank you for solution - this line works now and I mark it as answer. But I get another error "DataGridViewComboBoxCell value is not valid". On debug all code go through well and this error rises at the end. Maybe better to open new question for that...

Comment: just guessing, but in this manner you may need to convert the result to a .net-Type...? sqlDbType.Int -> int.. or maybe set the datatype of your datagridcolumn to nullable int (int?). I think SqlDbTypes are nullable so maybe the internal conversion results in int?